In Inkscape, why does editing a gradient color add an additional gradient?
I have a simple rectangular path with a linear gradient with 5 stops.

I want to change to stop 5's color from red to blue.  When I open the Linear Gradient edit box, I get the following result, which I expect-a single gradient that matches the shape (I named it for the blue devils-the team whose color I'm matching).

However, when I change the 5th stop color to blue, it adds a second gradient to the edit box.

I no longer want/need the first gradient (blue devil), but I cannot remove it.  If I click it, it removes the correct second one (1289) that I just created and replaces it with the first.  I cannot find anything in the online help or google to describe how this dialog box is supposed to work.  Any help or direction is appreciated.

With the gradient-tool active, there is a lock-button in the toolbar that determines whether it should change all instances (keep only one gradient) or create new gradients when editing an existing one.

Also, you can use 'File → Clean Up Document' to remove all unused gradients (and other unused things), or use the 'File → Document Resources' panel (added in version 1.3) to delete individual gradients.


It looks like you are using an older version of Inkscape. If so, then @Xrott has already given some options for you.
However, in the most recent version, currently Inkscape 1.4, the Fill and Stroke dialog has a new design, and additional functionality which could also help you here.
Basically, all you need to do is select the object with the gradient you no longer want, go into the Fill and Stroke dialog, Fill tab, then click on the Gradient drop down, and there is a Minus button in the drop down to remove the gradient of the currently selected object.

As to the why of your question, it's because Inkscape's default behaviour when editing a gradient is to automatically create a new gradient, rather than change the original instance on which it is based: a better-safe-than-sorry approach it would seem.  It would be kind of annoying if this wasn't the default behaviour.
If you imagine a scenario where the intention is to create different gradient fills on different objects, then the default behaviour is optimal. If it wasn't the default, then editing the gradient would also change the gradient of the original object, which would probably not be the result most people would expect.
However, as @Xrott has explained, you can easily change this behaviour by enabling the Lock button in the Gradient tool controls.
